# Can I use an Android App to behave like an Bluetooth A2DP client? e.i. stream music from my phone to an Android tablet

Tags: android, bluetooth, a2dp

I'd like to write an Android app that will run Tablet that can connect to my phone using A2DP and stream music from the phone.

The Android tablet will replace my car's stereo and navigation system.

I have already read quite a bit on Android Bluetooth API, I have imported a number of sample apps and more I read more I have the impression that the Android API only allows me to 'send' the  music stream and not to 'receive' it as I'd like.

Does anyone have any toughs or ideas on this?

Regards

Comment: are you still active ?

Comment: search exactly same App as you descried. Please tell current status of research of this question?